# Hover to expand nav, not click on trigger?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a navbar on the side of my page, I got the code from a website. Currently it has a button at the top that when the user clicks on it it expands out. However i'd like for it to expand when the user hovers over it. And un-expands when the mouse leaves it. But, it is coded using react-bootstrap so I'm not sure how I can edit this. Any ideas?

NavBar:

```
<div className="App container">
      <SideNav
        onSelect={(selected) => {
            // Add your code here
        }}
      >
        <SideNav.Toggle  />
        <SideNav.Nav  defaultSelected="home">
            <NavItem eventKey="home">
                <NavIcon>
                    <Link to="/"><img src={Dash}/></Link>
                </NavIcon>
                <NavText>
                    <Link to="/">Dashboard</Link>
                </NavText>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey="sites">
                <NavIcon>
                  <Link to="/sites"><img src={Site} /></Link>
                </NavIcon>
                <NavText>
                    <Link to="/sites">Sites</Link>
                </NavText>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey="tours">
              <NavIcon>
                <Link to="/tours"><img src={Tour}/></Link>
              </NavIcon>
              <NavText>
                  <Link to="/tours">Tours</Link>
              </NavText>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey="media">
                <NavIcon>
                  <Link to="/media"><img src={Media}/> </Link>
                </NavIcon>
                <NavText>
                    <Link to="/media">Media</Link>
                </NavText>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey="newSite">
                <NavIcon>
                    <Link to="/newSite/details"><img src={NewSite} /></Link>
                </NavIcon>
                <NavText>
                    <Link to="/newSite/details">Add new Site</Link>
                </NavText>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey="profile">
                <NavIcon>
                    <Link to="/profile"><img src={Profile} /></Link>
                </NavIcon>
                <NavText>
                    <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
                </NavText>
            </NavItem>

        </SideNav.Nav>
      </SideNav>
      <Routes />
      </div>
```

Comment: Are these custom components?  Can you provide a reference for where you got them from?

Comment: @slashp from here: https://reactjsexample.com/react-side-nav-component/

Comment: Can you share what have you tried? Sounds like onMouseEnter/OnMouseLeave should be used.

Comment: @ChrisTapay I have tried them but I'm not sure what condition to set the SideNav to to make it expand/retract. Ive just css using the :hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I think that this is a very bad, inaccessible UX design, but if you want to go ahead and do it, you'll need to implement an onMouseEnter handler, like so:

```
  handleOnMouseEnter(path) {
    const { history } = this.props;

    console.log("handleOnMouseEnter: ", path);

    history.push(path);
  }
```

In order to access the `history` object within props, you'll need to wrap your component in the `withRouter` HOC, something like so:

```
const WrappedApp = withRouter(App);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <WrappedApp />
  </Router>,
  rootElement
);
```

Then your NavItem would look something like this:

```
    <NavItem
      eventKey="sites"
      onMouseEnter={() => this.handleOnMouseEnter("/sites")}
    >
      <NavText>
        <Link to="/sites">Sites</Link>
      </NavText>
    </NavItem>
```

Please see [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9zx7k8kpxp) for a working implementation.